# My character's stats aren't the greatest, how can I deal with this?

Tags: realms-of-despair

When creating a character newer players often create sub-optimal statistic combinations for their characters, yet after a lot of effort to level them they're understandably very attached to them.

How can they deal with these deficiencies without simply starting over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial answer is that you'll have to find the stats on a piece of equipment isn't considered BIS.

The simplest example of this is having to use gauntlets of ogre power to gain strength on an evil thief.  Using these gives you 4 strength but only 3 damage roll.  You can shop the other slots to try to find an alternative that won't cost you 4 DR and hit point bonuses, but if you're stuck, you're stuck.

Having less than 20 strength will limit the number of potions you can carry and reduce your damage roll directly, and really isn't an option.

This is simply making do and isn't a viable long term solution.

The next alternative is to consider a different build.  Traditionally devout aligned characters have a much easier job adding stat bonuses than evil or neutral characters.  The equivalent hand wear for this thief would be Blessed gauntlets of the Templar with 1 strength on board, plus casts a spell on you for another 3 with a bonus of 6 DR.  They come with a -1 dexterity penalty but for most situations work just fine.

To really escape this situation ***many*** players will choose to start a new character with better base statistics.  This is a choice you get to make... creating new characters and leveling them becomes an obsession in itself looking for 10 extra hitpoints.

The alternative is to use glory to add stats to a piece of equipment.  At 75 glory each point it is not a cheap alternative but given quest rewards between 5-10 for minor quests it's also not a tremendous investment in time.  Many high end players will opt for the new character so they can add 1 DR for 150 glory or add hit points at 10 glory per point deeming these more essential but if you are attached to a character and make the investment then at some point you will be finished adding stats and may also start adding  other bonuses to your equipment.

Ultimately leveling a new character is a smaller investment in time but overcoming shortcomings will give you a character that you are truly invested in.